# "choked out in a final breath"

Tags: idiomatic-language

> She choked out in a final breath.

I am wondering if this sentence is grammatical. I think it is, but I am not sure. I am not sure if this sentence makes any sense, but to me it implies that someone choked mid-way during a breath that happened to be her last.

Answer (score 1):

**Choked out** usually means that someone said something with difficulty. For example,
She choked out the word "Oops!" in a final breath.
The phrase is transitive and needs a direct object, like "word" above.

Comment: Then what does "Florian Choked Out in Jiu-Jitsu Tournament" mean?

Comment: I find that at https://www.fightsports.tv/watch-florian-choked-out-in-jiu-jitsu-tournament/  . In that article a word is omitted in the headline to save space. It means "Florian was choked out", that it, his opponent defeated him with a choke hold.